# converting a huge string to Nan value in a Dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Is there a way to convert long strings into `NaN`values using pandas? I tried a direct approach like this

```
df = df.replace('.....',np.nan)
```

But there are so many of them.

Comment: Can you please tell what is too much length for you?

Comment: `df[df.apply(lambda x: x.str.len() > MAX_LEN, axis=0)] = np.nan`. Set `MAX_LEN` as needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can set them to `nan` using `str.len()`, let's generate random strings and stored them in a CSV

```
np.random.seed(0)
lens = np.random.choice(100, 100)
letters = re.findall(r'[a-z]', ascii_lowercase)
words = [''.join(np.random.choice(letters, i)) for i in lens]

df = pd.DataFrame(dict(words=words))
df.head()

# words
# 0 wmpctg
# 1 o
# 2 qpia
# 3 klnh
# 4 gnvpjgvl
```

And lets replace those above 5 characters:

```
df.words[df.words.str.len() > 5] = np.nan
df.head()

#   words
# 0 NaN
# 1 o
# 2 qpia
# 3 klnh
# 4 NaN
```